# Wordpress Bootstrap menu on mobile doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive-design

I have a page that uses the wp-bootstrap-navwalker to create a menu with bootstrap syntax in wordpress. It seems to work well, but on mobile devices the submenu links, dropdown-menu li, do not work.
If someone has implemented the wp-bootstrap-navwalker and it works well I appreciate your help.
This is the site where sub-links do not work: http://aagastropediatria.com .And this is the code used in the header:

```
<?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu'              => 'primary',
                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'depth'             => 2,
                        'container'         => 'div',
                        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse  navbar-ex1-collapse text-left ',
                        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );  ?>
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Works fine on Galaxy S6...

Comment: take a look at: https://github.com/Themekraft/_tk/blob/master/header.php